# I edited my last question so please take it off of hold

Tags: discussion

I edited my question [What food would be best for growing on Mars](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/99902/what-food-is-best-for-growing-on-mars), so please go and give answers.

Comment: Could you [edit] to add a link to the question?

Comment: I'm going to guess you mean "besides potatoes"?

Comment: All you need is love. And potatos. Mainly potatos. Also, you can *always* ask a meta question on your own question *if* you have a link to it. We arn't a forum and throwing meta posts on main might get you in trouble. I also find successful reopen requests make a detailed, articulate case for reopening beyond "I edited it" - what issues did you address?

Comment: Please make an account.

Answer (score 5):

The question was edited during the "on hold" grace period so was automatically entered into the reopen review queue when you submitted the edit.

It is also currently in the process of being reopened, having gathered one reopen vote so far.

Now that you've mentioned your question on Meta, too, that should bring some additional eyes to it.

I haven't looked at the question more than to check its status, but be patient and it should either be reopened, or you should receive feedback on what more you need to do to turn it into a reopenable state.